# Selenium Python selecting nth td when another td contains certain text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm very new to Python and trying to use for loop on rows of table in a website.

[image]

For above example table, I got to the point to find elements where second column contains Candy.

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[2]/div/font[contains(text(),"Candy")]')

**But I want to select td in C column if B column is Candy,** not just arraying second tds containing Candy.

I know my question isn't too clear but please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming this is your HTML code :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div><font>High</font></div></td>
            <td><div><font>Food</font></div></td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">ABC123</a></td>
            <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><font>High</font></div></td>
            <td><div><font>Candy</font></div></td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">BCD234</a></td>
            <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><font>High</font></div></td>
            <td><div><font>Candy</font></div></td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">CDE345</a></td>
            <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><font>High</font></div></td>
            <td><div><font>Drink</font></div></td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">DEF456</a></td>
            <td>N</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use the following expressions to select the desired td elements (XPath axis are used) :

```
//tr/td[2]/div/font[contains(text(),"Candy")]/ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

First we locate the `td` element which contains "Candy". Then we select the first td element, sibling of its first td ancestor.

Or shorter (assuming td element in column C contains a hyperlink) :

```
//tr/td[2]/div/font[contains(text(),"Candy")]/following::td[1][.//@href]
```

First we locate the `td` element which contains "Candy". Then we select the first following `td` element which contains a hyperlink.

Output in both case (2 nodes) :

```
<td>
<a href="http://example.com">BCD234</a>
</td>

<td>
<a href="http://example.com">CDE345</a>
</td>
```